# Lazy load MirrorType

Tags: swift, reflection, lazy-loading

Let's say I have something like this

```
struct A {
    lazy var b: String = { return "Hello" }()
}
```

If I try to reflect struct A and access the value for b through its `MirrorType` like so:

```
var a = A()
var r = reflect(a)

for i in 0..r.count {
    let (n, m) = r[i]
    println("\(m.value)")
    var c = a.b
    println("\(m.value)")
}
```

I get `nil` in the console both times. Note that the underlying value type is `Swift.Optional<Swift.String>`, and the variable name is somewhat confusingly `b.storage`. Is there a way to access the underlying value of a lazy-loaded variable using reflection or initialize it from its `MirrorType` or am I stuck waiting for someone to write a first-class reflection api for Swift?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MirorType is very limited in it's functionality. Besides that it's replaced by other functionality in Xcode 7 beta 4.

The point in your case is that the property has not been used yet. So it's actually still nil. The only way to make it not nil is by accessing the property by getting it's value. Unfortunately in Swift you can not do that by executing .valueForKey("propertyName")

If you are looking for a reflection library that is trying to get as much as possible out of Swift, then have a look at [EVReflection](https://github.com/evermeer/EVReflection)